# Where can I find information on all the familiars, including those not statted out in the PHB?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars

In the PHB, the spell [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) lists a set of creatures you can summon as your familiar; however, for some of them, I'm unable to find any stats in the appendix for them (particularly the octopus).

Where should I be able to find the statistics for all of these familiars?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All of these creatures are in the Monster Manual. However, you can *also* find the ones that don't appear in the PHB in the Dungeon Master's D&D Basic Rules posted [on the WotC web site](https://web.archive.org/web/20220119161420/https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/basicrules?x=dnd/basicrules).

You can also find the [*find familiar* spell](https://web.archive.org/web/20230623215633/https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) on D&D Beyond, freely available (as it is part of the Basic Rules), and from there follow links to the Basic Rules version of each of the possible familiars — like [octopus](https://web.archive.org/web/20211119000513/https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/octopus).

Answer (score 5):

They're in [“Appendix A: Miscellaneous Creatures”](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/miscellaneous-creatures) of the *Monster Manual*.